# What is the meaning of the Lie groups $ SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$?

Tags: standard-model, gauge-theory, group-theory, yang-mills

In simple terminology, what is the meaning of $ SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ ?
What does it tell us about the standard model? Keep it mind I am still an undergraduate, the answer I am looking for isn't very rigorous, but intuitive and meaningful.

Comment: It means the strong and electroweak interactions' [Yang-Mills theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory) have respectively the [structure constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_constants) of $\mathsf{SU}(3)$ and $\mathsf{SU}(2)\times\mathsf{U}(1)$. _Intuitively_ , the scalar multiplets of which we take a covariant derivative need to rotate as per these respective groups.

Answer (score 2):

Gauge symmetry is profoundly deep, so a maximum simplification will leave so much out. Nevertheless, what it means is that there are 3 forces at low energy. $U(1)$ is electromagnetism, with $1$ type of charge (charge), and one vector boson (the photon).

$SU(N)$ has $N$-types of charge and $N^2-1$ force carriers. $SU(2)$ is the weak force, with a doublet of charges and three vector bosons($W^+,W^-,Z^0$). (How those became massive and the lack of a $W^0$ falls under "The Higgs Mechanism", which must be ignored in a "simplest-possible" discussion).

The strong force (QCD) is $SU(3)$. There are three types of charge, which have been named red, green, and blue (aka "color-charge"). Particles with color-charge interact by exchanging $3^2-1=8$ gluons.